# Referencing the right name in angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I wrote an angularjs directive to simplify the rendering of a dropdown list:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('filterDropdowns', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '<a class="wrapper-dropdown" data-dropdown="{{ labelData }}">{{ label }}</a>' +
                '<ul id="{{ labelData }}" class="f-dropdown">' + 
                  '<li ng-repeat="item in items">' + 
                    '<a ng-click="setFilter(item.district)">{{ item.district }}</a>' +
                  '</li>' +
                '</ul>',
      scope: {
        label: '@label',
        labelData: '@labelData',
        dropdownValue: '=' // expects an object from the directive
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('dropdownValue', function(dropdownValue) {
          if (dropdownValue) {
            scope.items = dropdownValue;
          }
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Which I can easily use in my views in this manner:-

```
<div filter-dropdowns label="Districts" label-data="districts-data" dropdown-value="districts"></div>

<div filter-dropdowns label="Countries" label-data="countries-data" dropdown-value="countries"></div>
```

The problem is with the use of `{{ item.district }}` in my directive.

Depending on the object list I pass in to my directive, I actually need to render `{{ item.country }}` or `{{ item.area }}` so I **should not be hardcoding** `{{ item.district }}` in my directive's template or passing in `item.district` to `setFilter()`.

What's a good approach to solve this problem so that I need not hardcode `{{ item.district }}` in my directive code or passing in `item.district` to `setFilter()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allow the user of the directive to specify the item key name to use (perhaps called "displayableItemKey"):

```
<!-- Proposed usage -->
<div filter-dropdowns label="Districts" label-data="districts-data"
     dropdown-value="districts" displayable-item-key="district"></div>
```

Then linked to your directive scope:

```
scope: {
  ...,
  displayableItemKey: '@'
},
```

And finally in the directive template:

```
...
'<a ng-click="setFilter(item[displayableItemKey])">{{ item[displayableItemKey] }}</a>' +
...
```

Comment: it seems like there's some problems with this approach though. My `setFilter()` function does not seem to bind as a click event. Any idea why that might be so?

Comment: Ok, never mind... apparently I need to provide a way for the function defined in my controller to my directive using the `myFunc: '&'` notation.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `{{ item.district }}` to be more generic one like `{{ item.name }}` and you can convert the data source from district to name and then pass in the directive. Take a look at this code please.

<kbd>**[Demo on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mQ7wg/1/)**</kbd>

```
function Cntl($scope) {
    var districts = [{
        district: "PA"
    }, {
        district: "NJ"
    }, {
        district: "MD"
    }];

    $scope.districts = [];
    angular.forEach(districts, function (item) {
        $scope.districts.push({
            name: item.district
        });
    });

    var countries = [{
        district: "USA"
    }, {
        district: "Mexico"
    }];
    $scope.countries = [];
    angular.forEach(countries, function (item) {
        $scope.countries.push({
            name: item.district
        });
    });
}

angular.module('MyApp', []).directive('filterDropdowns', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<a class="wrapper-dropdown" data-dropdown="{{ labelData }}">{{ label }}</a>' +
            '<ul id="{{ labelData }}" class="f-dropdown">' +
            '<li ng-repeat="item in items">' +
            '<a ng-click="setFilter(item.name)">{{ item.name }}</a>' +
            '</li>' +
            '</ul>',
        scope: {
            label: '@label',
            labelData: '@labelData',
            dropdownValue: '=' // expects an object from the directive
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('dropdownValue', function (dropdownValue) {
                if (dropdownValue) {
                    scope.items = dropdownValue;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```